# Why is the Kauffman bracket well defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

I have seen the definition of the Kauffman bracket of a link diagram and I understand that I could compute this polynomial $\langle D\rangle$ for a given diagram $D$ by choosing an ordering of the crossings of my diagram and then by applying the definition.  However, I do not understand why the resulting polynomial does not depend on the ordering of the crossings that I have chosen?

Comment: Have you seen the state-sum definition?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yeah that is the definition that I have seen

Comment: Page 53 of [these notes](http://math.ucsd.edu/~justin/Roberts-Knotes-Jan2015.pdf) deals with making sure it's well-defined

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger  Thanks - that is just what I needed!